# mpdf in woocommerece myaccount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mpdf

I am facing problems in generating pdf using mpdf in wordpress myaccount page. Same code i used in themes **inc** folder which generates pdf as my need. Would you please suggest me what i am missing? I googled and found everywhere is used plugin but i don't wanna use any plugin. 
below is the code what i used in **woocommerce/myaccount/user_invoice.php**.
Mentioning that i also used mpdf library inside **woocommerece/myaccount/** directory.

Here is my code:

```
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF();

$html = "test data";
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
```

Here is the error what i got:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuild/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:280) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuild/wp-content/themes/rebuild/woocommerce/myaccount/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 7447

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuild/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php:280) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/rebuild/wp-content/themes/rebuild/woocommerce/myaccount/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 1736
mPDF error: Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file
```

Comment: The error means that before you call the function "$mdf->Output()" you send some output to the browser. It could be an "echo" or somethink like that. How do you call your PDF script? Directly in the theme? Over a hook?

Comment: I didn't use any hook. I just placed the mpdf library folder directly inside the woocommerece/myaccount/ directory. am i in the wrong way?